# Windows Phone 8.1 WebView navigation with x-form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, webview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to send POST x-www-form-urlencoded request using WebView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(request) on Windows phone 8.1

My code is

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(url));
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> content = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
content.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("shop_id","123456"));
request.Content = new HttpStringContent(new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(content).ToString(),Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Api returns me status which stands for "wrong id_number", but I'm sure it's correct 'cause I've tried using postman and it returns successful status code...
am i missing something?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the Header `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, try this code:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(url));
request.Headers.TryAppendWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.Content = new HttpStringContent("shop_id=123456", UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks, but i already tried that. i just navigated with string in which i put html form and post it to url :)

Comment: Did you use NavigateToString WebView method? and after that, did you click on a button which post the form to some url?

Comment: I added js to submit my form so i don't have to click anything

Comment: Did it solve you problem? If not, you can try to post contente via `WebView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage)`. In this case, you don't have to load `WebView` twice.